# 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported

Tags: python, pytorch

Hi I'm trying to train a multi-head classifier but pytorch cross entropy loss part says 
'RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported' 
I don't get what this means.
input for pytorch crossentropy is
tensor([[-0.4854,  0.1186, -0.0793,  0.2616,  1.0410,  0.5636,  0.2399, -1.2122,
-0.5685, -0.8250,  0.3312,  0.7864, -0.6592,  0.7546, -0.2060,  1.2761,
-1.1156,  0.5018,  0.0458, -0.4580, -0.5727,  0.4048,  0.5267, -0.0676,
0.3189, -0.8310,  0.3730, -0.0721, -0.1684, -0.1643, -0.6406, -0.8228,
0.2093, -1.5377,  0.0374,  1.0966, -0.1308,  0.7104, -0.4457, -0.5544,
-1.0206,  0.1226,  0.1906, -0.4855,  0.5353, -0.3179,  0.2177, -1.2350,
-0.0675,  0.8751,  0.3438,  0.6610, -0.0910, -0.5895, -1.3286,  0.1073,
0.3739,  0.0197, -0.2075,  0.7007,  1.1142,  0.5481, -0.5237,  0.7597,
0.4626, -0.0730,  0.1181,  0.7801, -0.1875,  0.0719,  0.1023,  0.7976,
0.3448, -0.2320,  0.5868,  0.2590, -0.5658,  1.1521, -0.0870, -0.5895,
0.0464, -0.3486,  1.7431,  0.1054,  0.6172, -0.1017,  0.1378, -0.6090,
0.8015,  1.6224, -0.4412,  0.0475, -0.7819,  0.2201,  0.0917],
[-1.0750,  0.2077,  0.0160, -0.3701,  1.0558,  0.2121,  0.2361, -1.3225,
-0.1253,  0.1130,  0.8529,  0.0655, -0.4037,  0.7598, -0.2645,  1.0476,
-1.0896,  0.6255, -0.0342, -0.0699, -0.0696,  0.3238,  0.0176,  0.0602,
-0.1978, -0.4527,  0.3064, -1.1201,  0.0634,  0.5955, -0.2385, -0.1715,
0.4089, -1.5835, -0.5719,  1.3851, -0.0403,  0.5482, -0.3158, -0.1783,
-1.0825, -0.1029,  0.1601, -0.6473,  0.3896, -0.6626,  0.1809, -0.3668,
0.7069,  0.8177,  0.6939,  0.4530, -0.4624, -0.4364, -1.1890,  0.2349,
0.2330, -0.2358,  0.4361,  0.1126,  1.2303,  0.5673, -0.5063, -0.0271,
0.3363, -0.1306, -0.2958,  0.5304, -0.2751, -0.1833,  0.5000,  0.8736,
0.2560, -0.1535,  0.8013,  0.0689, -0.8920,  0.9080,  0.4348, -0.5070,
0.0693,  0.1933,  1.0227, -0.7040,  0.9158, -0.7298,  0.0060, -0.6622,
0.3744,  0.5550, -0.0849,  0.0981, -0.6889,  0.1986,  0.1325]] - (shape  is torch.Size([2,95]) 
and target is
tensor([[ 1,  1,  3,  2,  0,  1,  3, 11,  3,  2,  1,  1],
[ 1,  1,  4,  2,  0,  1,  3, 21,  3,  2,  1,  1]] - (shape  is torch.Size([2,12))

Comment: Based on your target tensor shape, you are looking to use a one-hot encoding as the target tensor with PyTorch's CrossEntropy function. Is that correct?

Comment: Is this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/71144760/16733101 ?